# Load file into mysql table with correct escape

Tags: mysql

I intend to load a file (structure as follow) into mysql table.

```
"id","name","city","occupation"
"1","ami","Puchong","Engineer"
"2","sandy","Puchong (Equine Park)","Teacher"
"3","sam","Puchong "Puncak Jalil"","Doctor"
```

and expecting to obtain table structure as follow

```
|id|name|city|occupation|
|1|ami|Puchong|Engineer|
|2|sandy|Puchong (Equine Park)|Teacher|
|3|sam|Puchong "Puncak Jalil"|Doctor|
```

I'm loading the file using command below:

> load data infile '/home/kimi/my.txt' into table test fields terminated
>   by ',' enclosed by '"'  lines  terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

That would works for id 1&2, however I get warning message as such

> "Row 3 doesnt contains data for all columns".

I figured the extra " in 3rd column caused this problem. I **wondering if there's any way from mysql load argument side can tackle this?** 
Otherwise, probably I will do some clean up work prior loading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to escape the double quotes that you want to insert. This can be done by adding `ESCAPED BY '<char>'` to the command after `FIELDS`. The example below shows how to set a backslash as the escape character.

`...FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'...`

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks osdev0 for your proposed solution. :)
That's really a good idea.